# Create QR code inside itexsharp

Tags: c#, zend-framework

I am using ITexSharp for create PDF files with C#.
Now I need to create a QR Code, inside Itextshpar. I use Zen Barcorde dll for create QRCode, I creates code inside Picture Box. But I can not convert Picture Box object to Image for used with ITexSharp Image object.

Here's my code:

```
Zen.Barcode.CodeQrBarcodeDraw qrCode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.CodeQr;
PictureBox picQRImage = new PictureBox();
picQRImage.Image = qrCode.Draw("12245654", 50);
Image img = qrCode.Draw(pStrNuFactura, 50); //Can not convert explicit
Image img = (Image) qrCode.Draw(pStrNuFactura, 50); //Not working
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try use Free Spire.Barcode dll (free of charge) to generate QR Code image and insert that image into PDF. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/38268a/generating-qr-code-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
My solution was:

```
System.Drawing.Image imgZenBarcode; 
iTextSharp.text.Image imgQRCode; 
Zen.Barcode.CodeQrBarcodeDraw qrCode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.CodeQr;           
imgZenBarcode = qrCode.Draw( "123456", 50);
imgQRCode = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imgZenBarcode, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```